# Value of currentdate when report runtime passes midnight

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that runs each day at 2300h that pulls the data for the current day.  ie `where {datefield} = currentdate`

Normally the report takes 10-20 mins to run but sometimes it takes much longer and goes beyond midnight. Yes, I know it would be better to schedule this after midnight and use `currentdate-1`, however, I can't convince the report author to change it.

Since this calculation is done in the 'record selection' as a local formula, it's not part of the SQL statement.

The question is, when the report is compiled to display, is `currentdate` valued as 'when the report started to execute', ie the day before 2300h?  Or is `currentdate` valued as post midnight.

My fear is that it is the later and that whenever the report runtime goes beyond midnight, that we are missing data.

Comment: I don't know the answer but it's very simple to test it. Simulate that report now and after 10-20 mins display on that report time when created (Special fields - Data time). And if the time of the report is the time when report is finished then same happens with date.

Comment: This is a very genuine concern of losing the data. So try adding the current date in a global variable, and then using it further. And can you also focus on optimizing the same?